# How to run php scripts from web server

Tags: php, linux, xampp, lamp

I've started to learn about dynamic web pages so I dont know much about web servers or php or anything that's related to web. So I've installed XAMPP (to opt/lampp as default),and I want to test my first ever php script, but I don't know where to save it, because if I save it simply in opt/lampp it says object now found in the browser.[image] Where do I need to save my php scripts in the server to be able to run them in the browser?
Thank.

Comment: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110801180827AASy4Az

Comment: Everyone's a web developer nowadays huh? Search for htdocs folder, put your stuff inside.

Comment: figure out where your apache install's document root is. you can't just stuff your scripts into random spots on the server and expect apache to be able to find them.

Comment: yes I know,like I said I'm new to web things so I'm asking for advice,But anyways @Jordy thanks I think that solved my problem.

Comment: @BsD Doesn't matter, just try to google your issue next time. I searched for "Root folder XAMPP" and found lots of results :)

Answer (score 1):

You should save them under `www/`

Example under www/ you have a file called `test.php`
the correct url should be 
`localhost/test.php`

Another
under www/ you have a folder called `test_folder` that contains a file called `my1script.php`

the correct url should be 
`localhost/test_folder/my1script.php`

Comment: In XAMP the correct folder is actually `htdocs`.  I think you're confusing it with WAMP which DOES use the `www` folder.